# Search an XML Doc

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to figure out how to search an XML doc for a certain block (Block? String? I am new to this...) and return the rest of the...block? I am currently using XStream as my handler but couldn't find any tut on doing something as specific as this.

Here would be a sample of the code (Times 500,000):

```
<conversation>
    <input>HELLO</input>
    <response>
        <text>HELLO MATE</text>
        <hits>2</hits>
    </response>
    <response>
        <text>HOLA</text>
        <hits>1</hits>
    </response>
</conversation>

<conversation>
    <input>HOW ARE YOU</input>
    <response>
        <text>I AM GOOD</text>
        <hits>4</hits>
    </response>
    <response>
        <text>IM FINE</text>
        <hits>5</hits>
    </response>
</conversation>
```

It would search for input (ex. HOW ARE YOU) and then return the response block with the most hits. I assume this is an easy maneuver but my searching turned up nothing. Thanks mates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XQuery 1.0 this would be

```
declare variable $search as external;
let $c := //conversation[$input eq $search]
for $r in $c/response
where $r/hits = max($c/response/hits)
return $r
```

Comment: Isn't XQuery purely online? I was aiming for XStream since it seems simple, fast, and easy to understand

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "purely online". XQuery is widely implemented and ideally suited to this task. I haven't used XStream but it seems very low-level in comparison.